# Scala 2.11.x concurrency: pool of workers doing something similar to map-reduce?

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, future

What is the idiomatic way to implement a pool of workers in Scala, such that work units coming from some source can be allocated to the next free worker and processed asynchronously? Each worker would produce a result and eventually, all the results would need to get combined to produce the overall result.
We do not know the number of work units on which we need to run a worker in advance and we do not know in advance the optimal number of workers, because that will depend on the system we run on. 
So roughly what should happen is this:

```
for each work unit, eventually start a worker to process it
for each finished worker, combine its result into the global result
return the global result after all the worker results have been combined
```

Should this be done exclusively by futures, no matter how many work units and how many workers there will be? What if the results can only be combined when they are ALL available? 
Most examples of futures I have seen have a fixed number of futures and then use for comprehension to combine them, but what if the number of futures is not known and I have e.g. just a collection of an arbitrary number of futures? What if there will be billions of  easier work units to get processed that way versus just a few dozen long-running ones?
Are there other, better ways to do this, e.g. with Actors instead?

How would the design ideally change when the results of each worker does not need to get combined and each worker is completely independent of the others?

Comment: Are you aware of Fork Join pool?

Answer (score 3):

Too many questions in your question to address them all.

Basically, `Future`s will do what you want, you can create the `ExecutionContext` that better fits your needs. To combine the results: `Future.sequence`.